# Select max value in query for type

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, max

I have query

```
select order_no,
       line_no,
       type_id,
       delivery_date
from   orders
```

The value are

```
CO_01     1     A    2018-01-01
CO_01     2     A    2018-01-01
CO_01     3     B    2018-01-10 
CO_01     4     A    2018-01-01
```

There will be always one type_id B with diffrend delivery date. How to select for all rows another column called max_delivery_date that will have value delivery_date for type B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want, but we could try using analytic functions here.  The call to `MAX` below will find the `delivery_date` of the record having a `type_id` of `B`, for each group of records corresponding to a single `order_no`.

```
SELECT
    order_no,
    line_no,
    type_id,
    delivery_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type_id = 'B' THEN delivery_date END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY order_no) max_date
FROM orders;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Add inside select max for type B:

```
 select order_no,
   line_no,
   type_id,

(
  Select max(
   delivery_date) as max_delivery

  from   orders with type_id='B')  
As max_delivery_date

 from   orders
```